# Navigation controller back button when getting back from Facebook share

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm using the Facebook Share Dialog when sharing some content from my app.

I'm presenting the content I am going to share on a MaryPopin Controller and everything works perfect except for the navigation controller. It adds a "back button" when getting back from Facebook.

Any ideas why this is happening?

[image: Before leaving the app:]
[image: When returning the app:]

Comment: I'll suggest you to show your code of where the problem is. I highly doubt anyone here will look at your entire project, run it and find the problem you're having.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos, I've edited my question, I think you've misunderstood it, sorry about that.

Comment: "Any ideas why this is happening?" Since you haven't shown a line of code or a screenshot, I don't know what you want to happen or what is happening.

Comment: how about now? @TooManyEduardos

Answer (score 0):

You're using a navigation controller, which adds a "back" (or custom text) button by default to the navigation bar.

If you just want to hide the back button (not remove it or replace it), in viewDidLoad add this line of code:

Obj-C:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Swift:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer, if you look carefully at both of the pictures when the user gets back, the navigation title view "disappears" I think it is more like the option that somehow it is adding a new view controller to the navigation stack, don't you think? Cheers

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you want then or what the issue is